# write driver for simulate arduino uno as gamepad

Tags: c#, .net, driver, arduino-uno, gamepad

I connected two joy stick to arduino uno (ch340g) and I wanna use this as gamepad
but I don't know what library in c# (visual studio) can handle it
I search a long time. and now I don't know what to do and what to search.
thanks for answer

I couldn't find anything that help me

Comment: You can't use C# for stuff like that.

Comment: how can i do it? with which language? i wanna just write a program like X360ce

Comment: But simulate arduino as a gamepad or any HID device

Comment: This isn't possible with Arduino Uno because it uses a serial to USB converter and can't make its USB port behave like a HID joystick. It looks like there are existing projects for Arduino Leonardo to make it behave like a joystick, I'd start there.

Comment: ok.thanks for your answer.now, is there any library for arduino to simulate usb portocol (usb ver1 low speed) ? like soft uart or soft spi .

Comment: I dont want to buy another arduino, either arduino leonardo in our country is very expensive. there is an library for simulate usb portocol on another IO of uno?
or what can I do to write driver?

Comment: can this link help me?
if yes I spend my time on this...
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/gettingstarted/writing-a-very-small-kmdf--driver